# xrandr would not detect my second monitor

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, external-display

I am using linux, have 2 monitors and 1 laptop (3 screens in total) in my setup.

xrandr detect 2 displays (laptop + 1 ext monitor) and I get the same output on both external monitors.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     48.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I already checked posts around internet, but that cant really help since alreayd xrandr doesnt see my second external monitor.

I am expecting to have 2 DP detected, but not, only 1 is detected.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you post the output of `lspci -vnn | grep -A 12 VGA`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I fixed my issue by simply upgrading from ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 and now my DP are detected correctly. The kernel was too old, or the drivers not up to date.

```
    $ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     48.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-1-1 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-2-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This is how the output of xrandr i was expecting.
Hope this might help somebody if facing the same issue with the same distribution.